# How to create a prototype for this type of constructor?

Tags: javascript, oop, constructor, prototype

I explore the deep end of JavaScript.

Well, let's say I have a constructor function like this. Yes, I know this is a weird way of creating a constructor function, but ...

```js
function Animal(name){
  return { name };
}
```

And I wanna add a prototype property like `walk()`, but it doesn't work here. I know it looks stupid, but...

```js
Animal.prototype.walk = function () {
  console.log(`${this.name} is walking ...`);
}
```

**QUESTION: Is there any way that I can add this walk property as a prototype property?**

Comment: Yes, but use [`classes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)?!

Comment: I use classes in a daily, but just wanna understand how that works...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have to explicitly return an object that isn't `this` in the constructor, then:

Create the prototype object outside, then use `Object.create` inside the constructor:

```js
const animalProto = {
  walk() {
    console.log(`${this.name} is walking ...`);
  }
};
function Animal(name){
  return Object.assign(Object.create(animalProto), { name });
}
const a = new Animal('foo');
a.walk();
```

But this is strange, can you do it the normal way and assign to a property of `this` instead?

```js
function Animal(name){
  this.name = name;
}
Animal.prototype.walk = function () {
  console.log(`${this.name} is walking ...`);
}

const a = new Animal('foo');
a.walk();
```

or if you want to avoid listing `name` twice

```js
function Animal(name){
  Object.assign(this, { name });
}
Animal.prototype.walk = function () {
  console.log(`${this.name} is walking ...`);
}

const a = new Animal('foo');
a.walk();
```

Comment: Yes, I do it in a normal way, I was so curious how to implement that :)

Comment: What 's  the difference between `Object.create(animalProto)` and just `animalProto`. Like, why when I use `Object.create(animalProto)` the walk() method doesn't go to the __proto__ and copies in every single instance. But when I use `Object.create(animalProto)` it works. I'm talking about the **example #1.**

Comment: `Object.create` creates a *new* object whose internal prototype is the argument. `instance <- animalProto` But if you use `Object.assign(animalProto, { name });`, you only have one object, `animalProto`, that you mutated - but you don't want to mutate or return the prototype with the methods shared among all instances.

Comment: Why is it strange? I find myself using this pattern a lot lately. It makes the API more flexible to use and even a bit more concision for the client: gold() vs new Gold()...